# ubuntu installed using wubi is not working

Tags: wubi

I have 04 in my win7 64bit pc using wubi installer. I downloaded [wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) and followed the instructions.  It worked for a few days and now Ubuntu is not booting, it shows a black screen. I uninstalled Ubuntu from the Windows control panel and re-installed but it's not working.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you please specify which Ubuntu version are you speaking of?

Comment: WUBI is no longer recommended for your 13.04 version, and here's an explanation and discussion: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/wubi-unlikely-to-be-in-ubuntu-13-04-windows-users-lose-out

Comment: Sadly, wubi does not work with 13.04 for the most part. You will have to do a full install or install in a virtual machine.